# Clear QCPItemText in QCustomPlot

Tags: qcustomplot

I can't clear the items in a `QCustomPlot`. The method `QCustomPlot::itemCount()` always returns 0.

```
QCustomPlot *plot = new QCustomPlot(this);
qDebug() << plot->itemCount();                    // returns 0
QCPItemText *textLabel = new QCPItemText(plot);
qDebug() << plot->itemCount();                    // returns 0
```

Maybe `QCPItemText` is not considered as an item, but how do I clear `QCPItemText` then? Or reset `QCustomPlot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this after you allocate textLabel :

```
plot->addItem(textLabel);
```

From the documentation :

> bool QCustomPlot::addItem ( QCPAbstractItem *  item)
>
> Adds the specified item to the plot. QCustomPlot takes ownership of the item.
>
> Returns true on success, i.e. when item wasn't already in the plot and the parent plot of item is this QCustomPlot.